# Set Covering and Column Generation

Tags: python, reference-request, or-tools, column-generation, set-covering

I need some set covering and column generation examples in OR-Tools python.
If anyone can provide or direct me to some resources that would be great..!

Comment: According to community guidelines, you need to show what you have researched, what you tried, what did not work.

Comment: Hi Laurent, basically I was trying to formulate crew scheduling problem with help of metaheuristics and after going through research papers like [https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00291-020-00592-y] I started searching for your and Mizux's github which is only resource available for OR-Tools I guess but couldn't find any. Aim would be to try build something like [https://www.giro.ca/en-us/our-solutions/hastus-software/] but for only roster part that too only script as most of companies are using GA and other tools for that but as experiment I want to develop it with OR-Tools.

Comment: still too vague. The title is too broad. Develop with OR-Tools can means so many things...

Comment: I'm trying to modify bus driver schedule script of yours but with approach similar too nurseScheduling. I'll assume number of trips(shifts in that script) to be equal to number of drivers and then start with first driver and create his duty and so-on. But it's easier said than done so for that I was wondering set covering/column generation might be of use. I'm still trying to figure out how I'll make arcs for nonbreak driving & check for total driving time at same time. There our aim will be minimizing number of drivers by aplying maximize function on totalDriving done by individual driver.

Comment: Are you familiar with column generation? For what part of it do you want to use OR-Tools? To solve the pricing? The restricted master? For the column generation itself?

Comment: I was hoping column generation would fill up individual duties with trip in more efficient way so that we don't exhaust a duty with max running time too early wrt it's sign off time. Maybe I'm wrong but that was the idea behind it. I'm researching so I'm open to any suggestions so as how this task can be achieved.

Comment: I don't know what are duties and trips in your problem. If you want to use a column generation based approach, you need to have modeled your problem with a master problem and a pricing problem. If you haven't, no library can (currently) do it for you. Then, you'll be able to choose which component you want to solve with what

Comment: @user3237357 since you're explaining the problem in more detail in the comments, I suggest you edit your question and add all these details there.